# is it possible to set “iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE” to a single port?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

Hi i am trying to install this network Bonding through VPN software:

[Open source SD WAN daemon for linux](https://github.com/VrayoSystems/vtrunkd)

using this How to:

[How to set up a bonding VPN connection in Linux | Vrayo Systems](http://vrayo.com/how-to-set-up-a-bonding-vpn-connection-in-linux/)

on my CentOS 6.9 server running interworx with websites and email etc..

In the how to it calls for this command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

to enable the bonded network to reach the internet but using this command on my server will leave all the other services on it vunerable and it also prevents the email server from working. Is there a way i can do what it calls for but only on one single port? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is! All you need to do is:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p $tcp/udp --dport $port_number -j MASQUERADE`

Where `-p` is for the protocol (tcp/udp) and `--dport` is the destination port. I think in your case you will want `-p tcp` and `--dport 6000`.

Comment: Thank you very much Jaken551. Your solution has done the trick! :)

Comment: Glad it worked!